# Is it possible to reference Identity.Model library in a project .Net framework 3.5?

Tags: .net, vb.net, identityserver4

I have a project in VB.NET on .NET framework 3.5. I can't reference the Identity.Model library, as I got this error message:

> Could not install package 'IdentityModel 3.7.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Any suggestion, please ?

Comment: Upgrade the project to .Net 4.5 or higher. Please note that the IdentityModel version number has nothing to do with the .Net framework version number.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is - **NO** you cannot. Even the first version (1.0.0) of IdentityModel requires .NET Framework 4.5.

[Here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityModel/1.0.0) is the info about the nuget package. You will have to figure another way if you want to authenticate against Identity Server.

Comment: So, do you mean  Identity.Model library is the only way to authenticate against IdentityServer ??